# `crontab` fails to run Python3 code at boot (no GUI involved)

Tags: python, raspbian-stretch, cron

After searching for some time- I can;t find the reason that my python3 code won't execute during boot. I'm using Rpi Zero, using StrechLite OS.
Code run OK when is executed from command line.

crontab contains:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/pigpiod
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/guy/Documents/github/Rpi/SmartHome/tst.py &
```

**try 1:**

I've created a bash file (containing `echo "guy" >>log.log` )to see if cron job is running OK- and redirected its output to a text file. All went well.

**try 2:**

bash file was edited to run
 ( `python3 /home/guy/Documents/github/Rpi/SmartHome/tst.py` ) , but it failed.

**try 3:**

a simple python code was written, `123.py` containing a single line: `print("GUY")` to be executed  as : `@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/guy/Documents/github/Rpi/SmartHome/123.py >>log.txt` in order to check if something is python code during boot time, make it fail- but still python code is not executed during boot.

What is done wrong in order to run a python script this way?

Comment: What's in your python script? That might be failing due to path issues.

Comment: crontab outputs information to /var/log/cron.log - anything there to indicate what the failure is?

Comment: The pigpio daemon needs to be run as root.  Best to put the first line in the root crontab.  Also the daemon may take a second or so to launch.  Perhaps you need a delay before launching your script if it is using pigpio.

Comment: @Brick path was checked and is correct

Comment: @joan pig poof is running ok. The problem is execution of second line

Comment: @JaromandaX this is no such file in that directory

Comment: There is in all my stretch lite based RPi - do you have syslog-ng installed? Anyway, I see you don't have a user specified in the crontab entry - is this a user crontab? or is this one of  `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.*/*` files you have the entry in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying solving it with creation of daemon service (`systemctl`), which yield same unwanted result - I found the reason why:

using in `crontab` or daemon service - couldn't get `$PYTHONPATH` in time ( or boot sequence ) to find path needed to run a certain module I use.

so I added to my python code: `sys.path.append('/home/guy/Documents/github/Rpi/GPIO_Projects/lcd')` -in oder to find that particular module handling LCD display.

BTW- the above path is part of `$PYTHONPATH`, which probaby update after logging in, or running python IDE, but not when trying to automatically execute a code after OS boots up ( without logging in ).

Guy