# How can I run at boot or autostart an app with GUI?

Tags: python, python-3, raspberry-pi-os

I have a python script with a GUI that was designed with qt5, the script runs fine whenever I run it through the terminal or Thonny IDE. But no matter how much I tried, after trying many guides, videos, Chatgpt sessions I couldn't make it run on boot or AutoStart after boot to the Raspbian..

After I gave up I built a distributable file using `pyinstaller --onefile your_script.py`  and tried the same but with no success!.

Now at the end I am satisfied of having my application running by double clicking it's icon from the desktop which is as well not working as:

- the exe file should be in the same folder of the python scripts and other files.
- every time I double click it, it asks "Execute, execute in terminal, cancel".

Is there a way to just create a desktop shortcut to run the application directly?

Answer (score 0):

A search for `Raspberry Pi desktop autostart app` had https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=294014 as the first hit. It describes 4 ways to do what you want, depending on your OS and other factors.

One method requires using the command line. Assuming you are user `pi`:

```
mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi
cp /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
```

Edit the file `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and add a new line at the bottom, naming your process. The reference show this example, to start a Python 3 script:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@lxterminal -e python3 /path/my_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 12.4 Bookworm on RPi4 only the "Traditional" methods of that mentioned link [How to Use Autostart for Desktop](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=294014) worked for me.

I created a .desktop file and it executed in both the  /etc/xdg/autostart and alternately a created /home/pi/.config/autostart/ directories.

Comment: Seeing this question was asked BEFORE Bookworm this does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I've used crontab with varying success,

a guide here by another user using it with GPIO pins and python is below.

[crontab guide](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80259/crontab-fails-to-run-python3-code-at-boot-no-gui-involved)

It should be the same for GUI based scripts.